# Can't install vbox additions on a server 2008

Tags: virtualbox

Today I find myself unable to update the vbox additions on a Windows 2008,

[image]

I was running it with Administrator account, but it still complains about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to install additions from safe mode, it could help you.

Comment: We generally like to see answers supported by experience or references as well as instructions or rationale for the original poster (OP) to use.  Please expand upon your answer as to why this would help them, preferably backed by some community postings.

Comment: Just an experience, I made that step when have the same issue and it helped me.